# Сохранить настройки голоса спикера `random` и использовать повторно

Tags: python, pytorch, silero

Если я использую спикера `random`, можно ли как то сохранить настройки голоса и использовать их потом при синтезе?

```
import torch


def speech(text, `random`):

    language = 'ru'
    model_id = 'ru_v3'
    sample_rate = 48000
    device = torch.device('cpu')

    model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                              model='silero_tts',
                              language=language,
                              speaker=model_id)
    model.to(device)

    model.save_wav(text=text,
                   speaker=speaker,
                   sample_rate=sample_rate)
```